# Using 'Get-CrmConnection' to get Dynamics CRM connection is failed

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamics-crm

I want to use powershell cmdlet 'Get-CrmConnection' to get Dynamics CRM connection, but occurred an error. Connection string is correct, but I don't know why it failed.

Get-CrmConnection : Failed to connect to CRM: Unable to login to Dynamics CRM, Error was : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error,
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or fro
information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
At line:1 char:1

- Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=AD;Url=https://dev2gems ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CrmConnection], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -10,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.GetCrmConnectionCommand
  ```

Get-CrmConnection : Failed to connect to CRM: Unable to login to Dynamics CRM, Error was : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error,
om the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or fro
information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
At line:1 char:1

- Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString "AuthType=AD;Url=https://dev2gem ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CrmConnection], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -10,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.GetCrmConnectionCommand
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add -Verbose and -LogWriteDirectory 
then review the log there..  that will provide a lot more details.

You can also use the -InteractiveLogin (sp?) to get a UX to work with for creating the connection to test out the user.

Comment: I used another way 'Get-CrmConnection -OrganizationName orgname -ServerUrl https://consoto.com -Credential $Cred', it can get organization service normally. I don't know why the above method doesn't work.